# Playing with loops in python and not working

Tags: python

I am getting an error message from a simple looping exercise.

```
for i in range( 1, 4 ) :
    for j in range( 1, 4 ) :
        print( 'Running i=' + i + 'J=' + j)
```

> Error message:
>      print( 'Running i=' + i + 'J=' + j)
>   TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: us format print or str(i)

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with looping, you'd get the same error without the loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine an int and a string. `i` and `j` are ints so they need to be cast to strings to be concatenated with the other parts of your string.

You need to cast it to a string:

```py
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(1, 4):
        print('Running i=' + str(i) + 'j=' + str(j))
```

Comment: thanks that worked! l knew it was a little fix.